# Installing smlnj on macOS using homebrew not working

Tags: macos, sml

I am running to the following error when I am trying it install sml using homebrew

```
xxxxs-iMac:~ mo$ brew install smlnj

Error: No available formula with the name "smlnj"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: It seems to be a very recent addition. Have you `brew update`d recently?

Comment: yes, I have brew update... but not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. What fixed it for me was using

```
brew cask install smlnj
```

instead of

```
brew install smlnj
```